# Spring JPA save Single Entity cleared all existing postgresql table Data

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

## **IMPL Class has following JPA SAVE statment.**

```
            detailBlockEntity.setLastUpdateUserId(ctx.getUserId());
            detailBlockEntity.setOriginalUserId(ctx.getUserId());
            DetailBlockEntity detailtBlockEntityRsp = detailBlockRepository.save(detailBlockEntity);
```

## **Entity Class:**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

@Entity
@Table(
name = "detail_block",
schema = "pcrowner"
)
@TypeDef(
name = "StringJsonObject",
typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class
)
@NamedQuery(
name = "DetailBlockEntity.findAll",
query = "SELECT dtlBlock FROM DetailBlockEntity dtlBlock"
)
public class DetailBlockEntity extends BaseModelEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -12477273943220535090L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
generator = "detail_block_seq",
strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
)
@SequenceGenerator(
name = "detail_block_seq",
sequenceName = "detail_block_seq",
allocationSize = 10,
schema = "pcrowner"
)
@Column(
name = "detail_block_id",
unique = true,
nullable = false,
precision = 38
)
private Long id;
@Column(
name = "category_name"
)
private String ctgName;
```

Save execute on POSTGRE SQL Table cleared all existing data. Nothing strange in logs. It just happend behind the scenes. Please let me know if any one has any idea whats going on here?

I expected only one record to be saved in table. But instead cleared all data in table.

Comment: have you perhaps mistakenly set ddl-auto to create-drop?

Comment: @ColinRiddell Looks like that only

Comment: I dont have that property. Here is my resource yml looks like. 
jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        order_inserts: true
        order_update: true
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
          batch_size: 500
        id:
          new_generator_mapping: true
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz
    default-property-inclusion: non_null